# Is there a name for the side angle car crash scene?

Tags: cinematography

I have seen this type of shot enough that I frequently expect to see it anytime a car shot shows a side angle profile of the driver. I've begun to see a push in the other way now almost in acknowledgment of this type of shot, such as *Parasite* frequently using the exact camera angle with the Father frequently mentioning: "eyes on the road," to build tension, making the viewer almost expect a crash.

As someone who enjoys the youtube video essay format for movie reviews, I've learned that some film shots have earned themselves a special name because of how often they have been replicated. I have tried to google "Movies side angle car crash name" but I didn't find any hits. Does anyone know if this specific film shot has its own name?

**Some examples of this look are**:

*Whiplash* shows the truck as the camera pans back up
[image: Whiplash]

Here is a very similar angle from *No Country for Old Men* but the car crashes from behind the camera
[image: No country for old men]

Here is an example from *Parasite* which I think was designed to stress out the audience.
[image: Parasite intentionally stressing me out]

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/108961/origin-of-the-side-view-surprise-car-crash-shot?r=SearchResults

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/108961/origin-of-the-side-view-surprise-car-crash-shot?noredirect=1&lq=1 does have a similar analysis, without conclusion so it can't be marked as a dupe. TV Tropes calls it [Surprise car crash](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SurpriseCarCrash) which would technically answer this question.

Comment: @Tetsujin ah darn, I saw the title and skipped it because I thought it was asking something different but that does seem like the answer. I think if you made an answer with the tv tropes link I would give it the checkmark, but if its a dupe then I'll close it, thanks.

Comment: Personally, I'd be inclined towards marking as a dupe [which is not any kind of 'bad mark' just a linkup of two similar ideas] - though the questions aren't identical & the other has no real answer, any kind of link will push future searchers in the same direction. There is one auto-generated in the side-bar, but people tend to miss those.

Comment: Yeah that all sounds good by me! I don't have enough rep on this stack to mark as a duplicate but feel free to do that whenever. Cheers!

Comment: Also the Six Feet Under pilot episode (the father dying, which sets off the plot). There is a quick cut of the crash in [this intro video](https://www.metacritic.com/tv/six-feet-under/season-1/episode-1-pilot-613128).